# Use Bootstrap 4 theme with Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, laravel-5.5, laravel-mix

Only recently jumped on to the Laravel and Bootstrap 4 bandwagons, alas I have got Laravel 5.5 running with Bootstrap 4.0 no problem.
Sooo, I have getbootstrap.com Dashboard theme but I'm unclear on how to compile the themes assets and dependancies, i.e. what do I do with the gulpfile.js and package.json?

Note: I am using Laravel 5.5.34 and Bootstrap 4.0.0. I would rather learn how to compile assets using Laravel Mix and migrate from Gulp to Webpack, than simply copy the dist CSS to the public directory or link to the CDN in blade templates.

Comment: Maybe trying some front-end framework like `VueJS` which is in good contact with Laravel out-of-the-box?

Comment: I'm not sure how Vue (or React) could help. I think what I need to be looking at is migrating the TWBS gulpfile to webpack or something and adding the themes dependancies into the package.json... if I had to guess

Comment: Tutorial here https://www.5balloons.info/integrating-bootstrap-4-layout-to-laravel-project/

Comment: @Tushar that's a tutorial on basically how to make blade templates and include the TWBS CDN i.e. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">`
`

Answer (score 0):

I was going through the same dilemma and [this answer](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/theme-where-should-i-put-css-and-js) from Jeffrey Way has helped me.

I have created a css folder in resources/assets folder ( now it looks like resources/assets/css ). I copied all the css files that came with the theme to this folder.

And i updated the webpack.mix.js file in the root of the application

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
mix.styles([
      'resources/assets/css/app.min.css',
      'resources/assets/css/primary.css',
      'resources/assets/css/style.css'
  ], 'public/css/app.css');
```

Now when i run npm run dev all the css is compiled into a single file in pubilc/css/app.css and js in public/js/app.js

Note: My theme also came with a js file which is named app.min.js

So i inluded it in public/js/app.min.js as the main compiled file name is app.js. If your theme has a file app.js rename it to theme.js and place in the public/js folder.

You can call these the normal way you do after compiling them with {{asset('css/app.css') }}